# How to cerate L-shaped timeline UI in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-ui

I am trying to create a timeline-type UI in Flutter. Does anyone know how to create it or any package that helps me create it?

[image]

Comment: did u try timeline packages?  there r some packages available on pub.dev,

Comment: timeline package doesn't have this type of UI and I don't find any other package that can help me get this design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can take a look at this library，should meet your needs [flutter_fancy_tree_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_fancy_tree_view)